# How to install Snappy on Hadoop 2.7.6?

Tags: hadoop, snappy

I'm trying to install snappy1.1.3 on my hadoop 2.7.6 cluster, and following the guide https://code.google.com/archive/p/hadoop-snappy/.

However, after I finished every step from the guide, I ran the command "hadoop checknative", it showed that "Snappy:False". I already vim the hadoop-env.sh and core-site.xml, and restarted the hadoop cluster, but nothing changed.

Is there anyone who can give me some installation guide, with links or help? I would really appreciate that. Or, do I need to compile the source code of hadoop with snappy library, as some docs showed in some webs, but not official guide. Really hope that some one who installed snappy on hadoop successfully can give me some guidance!

Btw, I already insatlled gcc, g++ (both are 4.8.5), libtool, autoconf, automake,  cmake, and JDK 1.8, Java8. Would the version of JDK and Java affect the installation?

Really hope someone could help me. I've already been in this trouble for the whole week and struggled for it.

Update:
I already followed the guide from https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html,
and after the compilation I could find the snappy library in the path $ hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.9.1/lib/native. But I ran the command "hadoop checknative", the snappy still is false. Does anyone know what should I do after the compilation of hadoop source code?

Comment: "not official guide" -- Why not? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I followed the guide showed in the link, and when I try to native hadoop library, I encountered the following problem:" [ERROR] javadoc: error - Exception encountered while processing org/apache/hadoop/fs/class-use/HdfsVolumeId.html
[ERROR] java.io.IOException: could not create parent directories
[ERROR] javadoc: error - could not create parent directorie"               And one more question, the web seems the guide to build libhadoop.so, but not libsnappy.so. A little confused.

Comment: I typically install Hadoop following Hortonworks or Cloudera documentation using Ambari or Cloudera Manager. I believe both include snappy, so I've never really needed to build from source, sorry.

Comment: @cricket_007 Never mind, thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem on hadoop 2.7.6 and when change my version to 2.7.7, it solved. I didn't go more to check why this happened, but I also try different ways to solve it on 2.7.6 but finally I didn't find solution except upgrading to 2.7.7